# Android Internet permission in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, android-manifest

It seems like by default Unity doesn't put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to generated AndroidManifest.xml. These permissions are required in my project. Google doesn't give me direct answer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to **Edit**->**Project Settings** -> **Player**. Select Android, Build Settings, Change **Internet Access** from **Auto** to **Require**. You don't have to do this because Unity will do for automatically when you use any network API.

[image]

If that's not enough for you then you can modify the Android AndroidManifest by hand.

**1**. Open Unity. **Build** your project for **Android** just once. Don't close it.

**2**. Go to your Project Directory. A new Folder called **Temp** will be created by Unity after step 1. Inside that **Temp** there is another Folder called **StagingArea**. Go into the **StagingArea** folder and copy a file called **AndroidManifest.xml** into another folder in your computer. Modify/Add your own custom permission like the ones in your question.

**3**. Now move that modified **AndroidManifest.xml** file to **Your Project Directory**->**Assets**->**Plugins**->**Android**. If the **Plugins** and the **Android** Folders does not exit, create them.

Enjoy!

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for first method, I don't know why google haven't led me to some official documentation. the second solution is a bit more complicated, and actually until now I was using it, except one thing: I was picking AndroidManifest from another place - from /Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Apk/AndroidManifest.xml (this is on OS X environment)

Comment: @DeepThought Unity don't document some stuff. I suggest you master the second solution. You will need it when making your own plugins, if there is Manifest conflict or if you want a permission that is not available in Unity. You should get used to it if you do it 3 or 5 times. It's only copying file, modifying it and putting into into another directory.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is no longer present in the StagingArea-folder. Unity documentation about manifest-files, as of Nov-2020, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

Answer (score 1):

People that is using **Unity 2019.3 or newer**... (docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html)

Don't know if it's correct what I've done but it worked.

I added the permisions in the AndroidManifest doing this:

Following the steps of @Programmer but in the step 2 instead of going to the **StagingArea** folder I went to **YourUnityProject\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main** -> AndroidManifest.xml

Also I deleted a extra **"-"** before **"<manifest xmls..."**
Don't know if you will have this error too.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Unity 2021.2, you can generate an **AndroidManifest.xml** by following these steps:

1. Go to **Edit > Project Settings** to open the Project Settings window.
2. Select the **Player** tab, then open Android Player Settings.
3. In the **Publishing Settings** section, enable **Custom Main Manifest**.

This creates an Android App Manifest file and displays the path to the file. For information on the format of the Android App Manifest and the settings it configures, see the Android Developer documentation on [Android App Manifests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Then you can add the permissions you want to it.

[Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/overriding-android-manifest.html)