# How does Unity's Android permissions functionality work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Android Unity app that needs to be able to access the internet. The internet permissions are in the manifest, but when I go to settings it says 'No permissions requested'. From reading the internet, it seems that there used to be a checkbox to require the internet, but it seems it is no longer there. I have looked everywhere for how to handle Unity's Android permissions, but I can't find anything. Could you please direct me to a resource where I can find information about how to handle internet connections in Unity?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493936/android-internet-permission-in-unity ?

Comment: @AlexMyers I saw that, but it seems like those options no longer exist in Unity.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Internet Access > Required" menu option as shown in the screenshot? I'm using Unity 2018.3 and it's still there.

Comment: @AlexMyers Please see the picture I added. I'm also on 18.3, and the option is not there for me.

Comment: It looks like the option is there but greyed out for some reason.

Comment: What is your android version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use some apktools to decomplie your apk file and confirm if there actually has internet permission in AndroidManifest.
2. Check your URL, use https instead of http, in Android 8 and above, http is not supported.