# Unity game cannot access to internet

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, networking

I have an android app which needs to send a request to a server at some part. This works on PC but does not on android. Btw I am not sure this is the correct place to post this. Also, Edit -> Project Settings -> Internet Access is greyed out and the text is 'Require'. Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks...

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494257/4227611

Comment: That doesnt work for me. I guess this is a problem with android 8.0 and up as my friends phone can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the target API level to 27 in Edit -> Project Settings -> Player.